# LibGDX set the hitbox smaller

Tags: image, libgdx, collision-detection, game-engine, coordinate-systems

at the moment I develop a game in LibGDX and use rectangle for the collisions.

I need help to detect `collisions` with a rectangle. A had already done this, but i will put the `rectangle` on its center of `texture`. So the rectangle is smaller than the `texture` and will be in the middle of this.

I know already, I can set the `size` with: `rectangle.setSize` and put it with `rectangle.setPosition`, but how I can this put in the middle of my texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not set the `Hitrectangle` at the position of the `Texture`, but the `Texture` at the position of the `Hiterectangle`. Why? The `Texture` is only an optical presentation of your game. But it has no logic it needs to execute. The `Hitrectangle` instead has only logic, and no optical presentation. `Collision detection` is (a verry important) part of the logic. So i would set the position of the `Hitrectangle` where it should be, and then set the `Texture` depending on the position of that.
Lets say the `Hitrectangle` is 0.5 `unit`s (use the unit you want, maybe meters?) wide and high and the `Texture` is 1 `unit` wide and high. The position, given by the left, lower corner of the `Hitrectangle` is P(5,6), so you have to draw the `Texture` at: `P(5 - 0.25, 6 - 0.25)`.
Out of this you have the following formulas:

```
Texture.x = Hitrect.x - ((Texture.width - Hitrect.width) / 2);
Texture.y = Hitrect.y - ((Texture.height - Hitrect.height) / 2);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hmm.I don´t have an x and y coordinate on my Texture, so i draw the Texture on the position of my rectangle... Is that the wrong way to do that? Sorry for my bad english, I live in Germany :)

Comment: I also speak German, but i live in italy xD
You can set the position of the Texture in the draw() method. It is written in Lestats answer. My code should just help you understanding it, it is not copy-past code.
Have a look at the SpriteBatch.draw() methods and look for the one you need. The 2nd and 3rd parameter are most times the x and y position.

Comment: Okay :) In the moment i do this: Rectangle r = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50); batch.draw(texture, r.x, r.y); This is the right way or?

Comment: if the rectangle is the same size as the Texture yes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say these are your values:

```java
float dwidth = 1, dheight = 1; //your object visible size
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0.75F, 0.75F); //your rectangle, position initialized in 0, size smaller than the visible size
```

Then to draw the object correctly, you would do it like this:

```java
batch.draw(region, bounds.x-(dwidth-bounds.width)/2F, bounds.y-(dheight-bounds.height)/2F, dwidth, dheight);
```